# Floating point conversion and arithmetic

Tags: compiler-errors, floating-point, type-conversion, ocaml

I'm just starting to learn OCaml and I don't understand why this function does not compile.

add_half adds 0.5 to every value in the list; first, they have to be cast in float

example:

- input: [3;7;19;-4]
- output: [3.5;7.5;19.5;-3.5]

Code:

```
let rec add_half l = match l with
| [ ] -> [ ]
| x::xs -> let l = float_of_int x
           in (x + 0.5) :: add_half xs
```

the compiler gives following error:

```
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type int
```

how can I change this function to work?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, while you're converting `x` to a float, you're continuing to use the int value (`x`) instead of the converted value (confusingly named `l`). Secondly, OCaml has float-specific arithmetic operators, denoted by a trailing `.`. Floating point addition therefore needs the `+.` operator.

This compiles:

```
let rec add_half l = match l with
| [ ] -> [ ]
| x::xs -> let x' = float_of_int x
           in (x' +. 0.5) :: add_half xs
```